# Service worker for create-react-app does not ignore urls

Tags: service-worker, create-react-app, sw-precache

I've read through a bunch of the docs/issues for create-react-app and am trying to have my service worker not serve a specific url.

According to the comments in the ejected version of create-react-app

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
  // By default, a cache-busting query parameter is appended to requests
  // used to populate the caches, to ensure the responses are fresh.
  // If a URL is already hashed by Webpack, then there is no concern
  // about it being stale, and the cache-busting can be skipped.
  dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
  filename: "service-worker.js",
  logger(message) {
    if (message.indexOf("Total precache size is") === 0) {
      // This message occurs for every build and is a bit too noisy.
      return;
    }
    if (message.indexOf("Skipping static resource") === 0) {
      // This message obscures real errors so we ignore it.
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2612
      return;
    }
    console.log(message);
  },
  minify: true,
  // For unknown URLs, fallback to the index page
  navigateFallback: publicUrl + "/index.html",
  **// Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219**
  navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/, /^(?!\/que).*/],
  // Don't precache sourcemaps (they're large) and build asset manifest:
  staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/]
}),
```

Specifically this

> // Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
>         // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219

However, when I hit `localhost:3000/__, or localhost:3000/__auth or localhost:3000/__que`

all of them still hit my index.html.

How do I get the service worker to ignore urls?

Comment: Have you fixed this? Really annoying.